# Mac Won't Enter Firmware Restoration Mode

Tags: imac, startup, restore, firmware

I'm trying to solve a real head-scratcher of an issue on an older iMac (model 6,1, a 2006 24" white model) and want to eliminate the firmware as a possible culprit.

To that end, I've created a firmware restoration CD (v1.4, which lists this model number as compatible) and I'm following the instructions to use it.

With the disc not inserted, I'm holding the power button and waiting for the power LED to flash three times rapidly, three times slowly, and three times rapidly as described, however this is not happening.

Instead what's happening is the light flashes very rapidly for a second or so, then a long tone plays and the computer immediately starts up normally; I'm not being given any reasonable opportunity to insert the disc. I've tried with the disc already inserted and this appears to make no difference.

What does this indicate? As far as I can find the long tone indicates that the iMac is in EFI recovery mode, but it shouldn't be as the disc isn't being accepted (or isn't inserted in the first place), and nothing different happens, it just immediately starts up.

Granted, firmware restoration is probably a long-shot at fixing an odd issue with an old machine, but it seems strange that I can't get it to work at all!

Comment: This looks very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me...

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin. What is the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Does it matter? Even if bad firmware isn't the answer, the firmware restoration CD *should* work, so the fact that it doesn't is it's own problem.